# Proof Involving Identity Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I was solving a problem and would like to confirm if my proof is correct or not.

Find all entire functions $f$ such that $f(z) = e^{z^2}$ for $z = 1, 1/2,1/3...1/n...$

I'm thinking of using the well known identity theorem here,

take $g(z) = f(z) - e^{z^2}$
this $g(z) = 0$ for $z =  1/n , n \in \mathbb{N}$

since $0$ is the limit point of the zeroes, therefore by identity theorem

$g(z) = 0 \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$

hence $f(z) = e^{z^2}$ is the only map.

Is this correct or do I need to supply more details?

Comment: That is exactly how it is done.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much.

Comment: how is 0 the limit point of the zeros?